# Warning: Heartbeat: MP-CLOCKSKEW. Can this be a cause for multiple hosts restart in a MarkLogic cluster?

Tags: marklogic

I have encountered an error -

```
  Warning: Heartbeat: MP-CLOCKSKEW Detected clock skew: host xyz.abc.com skewed by 156 seconds
```

Can detection of clock skew, be a cause for MarkLogic server restart? I went through a manual https://help.marklogic.com/knowledgebase/article/View/24/0/synchronizing-system-clocks-in-a-cluster

but it doesn't state about MarkLogic server can get restarted. Perhaps, there might be other reason.

Comment: Not to my knowledge. Did you have issues with restarts?

Comment: Yup. I see this line in error log followed by Warning: Hung 64 sec and then either master forests states are changing or MarkLogic server got restarted. But I'm uncertain that this is the reason. There can be other reasons as well like huge data ingestion with very high throttle. Not sure

Comment: CLOCKSKEW can lead to problems and 156 seconds is  long time to be off. Are you using NTP?

Comment: Look for other errors in your logs for "XDMP-" or "SVC-" or "exception"  especially around that timeframe, to see what other errors or exceptions may have been occurring within that timeframe.

Answer (score 0):

If you see "Marklogic restarting" in the error log directly after (and within a few ms) of a prior error -- then its likely a directly invoked restart.  Otherwise its likely a restart caused by the symptoms occurring later -- possibly but not necessarily -- a result of the detected problem.
You will likely not be able to conclusively determine, its unlikely a direct cause of anything but very likely an indirect cause of *many problems*.
But if you do fix the clock skew and then fewer problems arise -- "Thats a good thing"
System restarts are a very last resort in MarkLogic.  It is a tough architectural decision to decide when a problem is bad enough to warrant a restart vs. less invasive methods (such as transaction abort, thread termination etc).  The determination of severity of an issue from 'info' to 'critical' is rarely 100% objective and deterministic at the point its detected, and almost never is the metric detected the actual underlying cause -- its a symptom.
For example "Out Of Memory" isnt the *cause* of a severe problem, its a symptom that somewhere else there is a problem that is using too much or not freeing memory.

If MarkLogic (company) knew exactly how every case of an severe problem that  caused (unintentional)  as opposed to required (intentional) a restart there would be none of the former.  Therefore your question cannot get much better of an 'official' answer.

The official answer is there are *many serious problems* known to be caused by clock skew, and that there are *known* to be others -- they simply have not specifically been tested, likely because the known ones are so severe that "Don't Do That" is in fact the best answer.

Any of the stated problems and an uncountable number of the unstated problems *can potentially lead to a restart*.   This is inherent.  A problem so severe that it cannot be automatically resolved and managed by the internal code and is explicitly not tested, by definition, is one that could lead to problems sufficient to restart or crash the server.

Yes that sounds  vague.   Yes its true.
Heres a simplier example.   "Will putting my server under water cause a Restart".

Maybe. Maybe not.  You wont get "Server under water, restarting" messages. It's not tested. You won't be able to get a definitive answer. Its definitely not a good idea. Can I prove that ?  I don't want to spend the $ to :)

The best answer to that is "Don't Do That"
Same for clock skew.  Time coherency is *extremely important for distributed transactional systems.  Don't mess with time, its not very forgiving.